# Множественные запросы на разрешения(runtimepermissions) в Android. Не корректное срабатывание.

Tags: android

Необходимо в приложении запрашивать разрешения пользователя. Но по непонятной мне причине, нижеприведенный код отрабатывает не совсем так, как задумывалось.
По задумке, после того как пользователь нажал "Отмена" в окне запроса разрешения, то появляется окно с установленной надписью и кнопками

```
showPermissionDialog
```

Оно и появляется, но только если запрос идет один. Если же запросов несколько, то в системном окне запроса при нажатии "Отмена", снова появляется это же системное окно, а не

```
showPermissionDialog
```

Помогите понять почему так происходит?

```
package com.test.mytest.runtimepermissions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 10001;
private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 10002;
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE = 10003;
// объявляем разрешение, которое нам нужно получить
private static final String READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
private static final String READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String READ_CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // проверяем разрешения: если они уже есть,
    // то приложение продолжает работу в нормальном режиме
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION)) { Toast.makeText(this, "READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION. Разрешения есть, можно работать", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else
    {
        // иначе запрашиваем разрешение у пользователя
        requestPermission(READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }

    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) { Toast.makeText(this, "READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Разрешения есть, можно работать", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else
    {
        // иначе запрашиваем разрешение у пользователя
        requestPermission(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    //Запрос на звонки
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_CALL_PHONE)) { Toast.makeText(this, "READ_CALL_PHONE. Разрешения есть, можно работать", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    else
    {
        // иначе запрашиваем разрешение у пользователя
        requestPermission(READ_CALL_PHONE, REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE);
    }


}
private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission)
{
    // проверяем разрешение - есть ли оно у нашего приложения
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
   // super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE:
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE  получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else {  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE не получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
        }
      //  break;
     /*Если тут вызывать только у примеру case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, то всё работает как надо. Но если оставить как сейчас, то showPermissionDialog не вызывается в случае отмены в системном окне запроса. Но если разрешить, то в следующем запросе REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE при нажатии Отмены showPermissionDialog появляется*/
       case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else {  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION не получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к GPS",REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);}
        }
     //   break;

        case REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE:
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else {  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE не получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к звонкам",REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE);}
        }
      //  break;

    }

}
private void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
{
    // запрашиваем разрешение
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
}
private void showPermissionDialog(Context context, String text,  final int RE)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(title + text); //text/" требует разрешение на доступ к положению"

    String positiveText = "Настройки";
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { openAppSettings(RE);  }
    });

    String negativeText = "Выход";
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
private void openAppSettings(int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS); //REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CALL_PHONE,REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE); }
}

private void requestApplicationConfig(final String READ_ACCESS, int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_ACCESS)) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Теперь уже разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пользователь снова не дал нам разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermission(READ_ACCESS, REQUEST_ACCESS);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Потому что вы их по одному набрасываете в `onCreate`, вот они по одному и выскакивают. Пока вся очередь не пройдет, ничего другого не увидите.

Answer (score 0):

В общем получилось вот так:

```
package com.test.mytest.runtimepermissions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 10001;
private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 10002;
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE = 10003;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 10004;
// объявляем разрешение, которое нам нужно получить
private static final String READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
private static final String READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String READ_CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
private static final String READ_CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
/////////
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS={
        READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        READ_CALL_PHONE,
        READ_CAMERA
};
private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST=1337;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if(!canAccessCallPhone() || !canAccessFineLocation() || !canAccessCamera())
        {
            requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);
        }
        else Toast.makeText(this, "ВСЕ Разрешения есть, можно работать", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



}


private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission)
{
    // проверяем разрешение - есть ли оно у нашего приложения
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if(requestCode == INITIAL_REQUEST)
    {
        if (canAccessFineLocation()) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else
        {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к GPS",REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        }

        if(canAccessCallPhone()) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else
        {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к звонкам",REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE);
        }


        if(canAccessCamera()) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к камере",REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

    }


}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessFineLocation() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCallPhone() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCamera() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean hasPermission(String perm) { return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm)); }

private void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
{
    // запрашиваем разрешение
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
}


private void showPermissionDialog(Context context, String text,  final int RE)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(title + text); //text/" требует разрешение на доступ к положению"

    String positiveText = "Настройки";
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { openAppSettings(RE);  }
    });

    String negativeText = "Выход";
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
private void openAppSettings(int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS); //REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CALL_PHONE,REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {  requestApplicationConfig(READ_CAMERA,REQUEST_CAMERA); }
}

private void requestApplicationConfig(final String READ_ACCESS, int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_ACCESS)) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Теперь уже разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пользователь снова не дал разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermission(READ_ACCESS, REQUEST_ACCESS);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Но что-то я непойму. И куда теперь писать код? Вот куда вписать 
 TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NUMBER: " + phoneMgr.getLine1Number(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Куда не впишу требует заново всё создавать. Хотя права по идее уже есть у приложения